# Taking a textbox's text in a listview

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a ListView, and i have an `asp:TextBox` in it:

```
        <table>
              <asp:ListView ID="Users" runat="server" 
                    DataKeyNames="Email" onitemediting="Users_ItemEditing" 
                    onitemupdating="Users_ItemUpdating">
               <LayoutTemplate>
               <tr>
               <td style=" width:34%;border-bottom:1px solid black;">Name</td>
               <td></td>
               </tr>
               <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
               </LayoutTemplate>
               <ItemTemplate>
               <tr>
               <td>
               <%# Eval("name") %>
               </td>
               <td>  
               <asp:LinkButton ID="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit">Edit</asp:LinkButton> 
               </td>
               </tr>
               </ItemTemplate>
               <EditItemTemplate>
               <tr>
               <td>     
               <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:TextBox> 
               </td>
               <td> 
               <asp:LinkButton ID="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update">Update</asp:LinkButton> 
               </td>  
               </tr>
               </EditItemTemplate>
               </asp:ListView>

            </table>
```

when i change the text in the text box and then try to get it in the code behind like this:

```
   protected void Users_ItemEditing(object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
   {
       this.Users.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
       BindTheListView();
   }
   protected void Users_ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
   {
       string Name=((TextBox)Users.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("Name")).Text;
   this.Users.EditIndex = -1;
   BindTheListView();
}
```

*`BindTheListView()` Binds the listview `Users`, it works.

it takes the original text of the `TextBox`, the `<%# Bind("name") %>` instead of what i have just changed.

The update function is a lot longer so i put only what i think is needed. i know the `Name` recives the text that wast before in the textbox because the updtade function didnt work(it didnt change anything in the database) so i run debugg and i saw that `Name` recives what was before

How can i take the text that i have entered the `textbox` and not what was in it?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you show us entire method from code behind where you try to retrieve that value in?

Comment: i updated the main post

Answer (score 1):

In User.ItemUpdating get new values from e.NewValues collection instead.

EDIT:

Use DataList instead of ListView:

```
<table>
    <asp:DataList ID="Users" runat="server"  DataKeyField="Email" OnEditCommand="Users_ItemEditing"
        OnUpdateCommand="Users_ItemUpdating">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 34%; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
                    Name
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("name") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update">Update</asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</table>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Users_ItemEditing(object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Users.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
        BindTheListView();
    }
    protected void Users_ItemUpdating(object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string Name = ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("Name")).Text;
    }
```

Comment: Like this?                                                   
       string Name = ((TextBox)Users.Items[int.Parse(e.NewValues.ToString())].FindControl("Name")).Text;

Comment: Like this: string Name = e.NewValues["name"]; Debug 'updating' method and see if you get any items in 'e.NewValues' collection. It may only work if you bind your ListView from sql or object datasource by setting DataSourceID property but try it.

Comment: i have checked it, and the items in 'e.NewValues' are the same as before.( even if i change the text on the textBox it is still as it was before)

Comment: Looks like it's known problem with ListView control if you don't bind it from SqlDataSource providing DataSourceID. Change your ListView control to DataList. I updated my answer with example that uses DataList.

Comment: I tried changing it to DataList, but it made no difference :(, you say that if i will bind it from a datatable it will work?

Answer (score 0):

on Page Load use

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    BindTheListView();
}
```